# How to pass textbox client ID to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a JS function to make textbox operation. When I sent textbox client ID, I am receiving this syntax error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=txtEposta.ClientID%>

How can I fix this error? I am very new to JavaScript. Whatever I tried I cannot find a solution. Please help.

```
function SearchText(clientID) {
    console.log("#" + clientID);
    var availableTags = ["gmail.com", "hotmail.com", "mynet.com", "yahoo.com", "outlook.com", "windowslive.com"];
    $("#"+clientID).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        matchCase: false,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            var oldValue = $("#" + clientID).val();
            var value = oldValue + ui.item.value;
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#" + clientID).val(value);
        },

        select: function (event, ui) {
            var oldValue = $("#" + clientID).val();
            var value = oldValue + ui.item.value;
            $("#" + clientID).val(oldValue);
            event.preventDefault();
        },

        minLength: 0
    });
```

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="TextBoxControl.WebUserControl1" %>

<link href="/Script/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../common.js"></script>>
<div>   
<asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="txtEposta" MaxLength="100" Width="250px" onKeyPress="javascript:SearchText('<%=txtEposta.ClientID%>');"                  
    ControlType="AlpfaNumericAndSymbols" AllowSpaces="False" Visible="true"></asp:Textbox>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply replace the `txtEposta.ClientID` with `this`.

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="txtEposta" onKeyPress="javascript:SearchText(this);"

<script>
    function SearchText(element) {
        alert(element.id);
    }
</script>
```

If you really want to use ClientID you will have to add it programatically

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEposta"></asp:TextBox>

<script>
    function SearchText(element) {
        alert(element);
    }
</script>
```

and then in `Page_Load`

```
txtEposta.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", string.Format("javascript:SearchText('{0}');", txtEposta.ClientID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `ClientIDMode` in you Textbox to `Static`. Thes will make the ClientID be the same as the id on server side. Don't forget to change the `onKeyPress` argument.

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="txtEposta" ClientIDMode="Statis" MaxLength="100" Width="250px" onKeyPress="javascript:SearchText('txtEposta');"                  
ControlType="AlpfaNumericAndSymbols" AllowSpaces="False" Visible="true"></asp:Textbox>
```